# Which is better to use for the server of a basic server/client socket implementation, "socket" or "socketserver"?

Tags: python, sockets, socketserver

I've read that socketserver is easier to use, but for someone who is just learning about sockets, which would be quicker and more beginner-friendly, socket or socketserver?  For a very basic client/server setup using stream sockets. (Python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`socket` is the low-level interface which `SocketServer` (as well as other networking code) is based off of. I'd start out learning it, whether you plan to use it directly or not, just so that you know what you're working with.

Also, `SocketServer` is of no use if you're writing client code. :)

Comment: right, i meant for the server side :)  that's what i was thinking.  thanks!